# Why doesn't SE work in IE7?

Tags: support, design

Most pages have no formatting and most scripts break while viewing the pages in IE7.  Why is this?  Was this overlooked?

Comment: we can't reproduce this..

Comment: why are you using IE in the first place?

Comment: School limitations -__-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this happen when IE7 has an error while downloading a linked resource (e.g. a script or stylesheet) and then caches the corrupted resource. Try pressing Ctrl+F5 to thoroughly refresh the page and see if it looks okay.

Are things also broken on the meta site? Does it look different from [this screenshot](http://browsershots.org/screenshots/554a26cd84959ee2a9f40e40ba5a44a1)?

---

Here is an image of our logo, see if you can see it below or [click this link](http://cdn.sstatic.net/gamedev/img/apple-touch-icon.png).

[image: game dev stack exchange logo]

Comment: Yes.  No formatting and a lot of the scripts are broken.

Comment: So your machine looks different from that IE7 screenshot? Then it's a problem on your end, not the site itself. The stylesheets and scripts are loaded from cdn.sstatic.net - make sure that site isn't being blocked by something (hosts file, firewall, browser extension). For example are you able to see [this image](http://cdn.sstatic.net/gamedev/img/apple-touch-icon.png)?

Comment: When you earlier had a link on that site, multiple browsers (not IE curiously) had the same issue I was having.

Comment: [Here is the link](http://browsershots.org/http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) from earlier; I removed it because it timed out before reaching the IE tests. Is the page on your computer looking like the two screenshots of the Dillo browser? Because the Dillo browser doesn't support scripting or anything other than plain HTML and images, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dillo) - so it actually looks correct considering the browser. Furthermore, you still haven't answered my questions and I'm trying to help you diagnose your problem...